# VBA macro if cell contains a specific value then return specific texts to a certain range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that tracks engine status from Sales and Production departments. Columns A - M in the workbook contain data necessary to deem the engine status. Columns N - AR are used to track engine status with the following column order: Sales, Production, Day 1, Status. That repeats till Day 8 (i.e. Sales, Production, Day 8, Status).

[Sample file](https://liveconcordia-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/t_oa_live_concordia_ca/EYFFbdaNPAhIvCRQFnCWK2wBSwpB46IVmG4QgbAyQJr5Pg?e=mGUvfd)

Column AV is called "MB51 Shipped" and column AY is "Title Transfer".

I'd like to create a macro so that:

**1) If `Shippep` in column AV, then the empty remaining Days will have `Rollup` in both Sales and Production columns.**

[See print screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZd3b.png)

Ex: in the attached print screen (the column may be slightly different from the sample file but the concept is the same), note that data was entered up to Day 6 (columns AH - AK) and a user put `Shipped` in column AV after entering Day 6's status. Here, I'd like the macro to return `Rollup` for every empty Sales and Production cell after Day 6 as highlighted in black from the screenshot.

Another example, if after entering Day 2's status (columns R - U), the user puts `Shipped`, then every Sales and Production cell after that will return `Rollup`.

**2) If the last entered Sales cell says `Title Transfer` then return `x` in column AY (51st column)**

[See print screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBPBB.png)

So in my print screen, the last entered Sales cell having `Title Transfer` status is column Z of Day 4, the macro should then  return an `x` in column AY as shown in the screenshot.

I don't have any programming knowledge so any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

A very rough draft, but you can add this code to your `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` event

Like this:

[image: Code position]

**Code:**

```
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim counter As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False

' Check if header is "MB51 Shipped"
If Me.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value = "MB51 Shipped" Then

    ' Get last column based on first row
    lastColumn = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Check all cells in row and find matches for Sales and Production
    For counter = 1 To lastColumn

        ' Check if header match and cell is not empty
        If (Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Sales" or Me.Cells(1, counter).Value = "Production") And Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = vbNullString Then

            Me.Cells(Target.Row, counter).Value = "RollUp"

        End If

    Next counter

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Alison, my code does this: `If Shippep in column AV, then the empty remaining Days will have Rollup in both Sales and Production columns.` Question: What does "Status" columns have to do with that part?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for the codes, however I tried them but nothing happened. Also, I think I didn't specify this in my post but those Status columns of mine have formula with them. Not sure if the codes would erase them? I'd like to only return Rollup in Sales and Production cells because the Day cells already have their own formula and sometimes a user might change the status right after he enters and see the formula gone would create unnecessary trouble. Thanks again!

Comment: Code checks if header is Sales or Production and the cell value is empty. If it does, it changes the cell value to Rollup

Comment: Hi very sorry for the confusion. The codes work now, I realised that when I copied and pasted your codes, they weren't fully copied and that was why at my first attempt it didn't work. Thanks very much. Can you please advise how to get the second part (Title Transfer) to work? Thanks again

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer (check mark at the left) and please post a new question with the second part, and drop the link here (comments) so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Just noticed the  added coded stopped the macro in my file somehow. Because the macro in the file helps return values for Day cells based on `IF` statements, now, after adding your code, the macro did return `Rollup` in Sales and Production but didn't return any value in Day cells

Comment: If you notice  in the image, I left all the remaining code intact. You should too